# NewType for Callables in Python

Tags: python, mypy, typechecking

I would like to define two types `Shape` and `Square`. Here `Square` is a subclass of `Shape`.

```py
Shape = NewType('Shape', tuple[int, int])
Square = NewType('Square', Shape)

def square_area(sh: Square) -> int:
    a, b = sh
    return a * b

def shape_area(sh: Shape) -> int:
    a, b = sh
    return a * b
```

I would define an additional type `SquareCalculator` as follows:

```py
SquareCalculator = NewType('Calculator', Callable[[Square], int])

def get_calc() -> SquareCalculator:
    return square_area
```

The above code leads to the following errors in mypy:

```
newtyp.py:10: error: String argument 1 "Calculator" to NewType(...) does not match variable name "SquareCalculator"
newtyp.py:13: error: Incompatible return value type (got "Callable[[Square], int]", expected "SquareCalculator")
Found 2 errors in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

Is there a way around this? Note that I would like to maintain the difference in `Shape` and `Square` to ensure type-checking catches errors when they are inter-changed.

Comment: Are you sure you mean to use `NewType` and not a type alias? The point of `NewType` is to create types that are incompatible with their origin types. It's impossible to get something compatible with `SquareCalculator` without an explicit cast, which there aren't any in your code.

Comment: The first error, at least, is fixed by using `'SquareCalculator'` instead of `Calculator`; you cannot, however, define a `NewType` for something that isn't subclasslable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SquareCalculator` should be a type alias, not a newtype, otherwise you need to use `typing.cast`.

Current syntax:

```
from typing import TypeAlias
from collections.abc import Callable

SquareCalculator: TypeAlias = Callable[[Square], int]
```

Python 3.12 syntax:

```
from collections.abc import Callable

type SquareCalculator = Callable[[Square], int]
```