# How to distinguish between two identical TypeAlias of Callable in Mypy

Tags: python, mypy

I have two calculator types, `Calculator1`, `Calculator2` defined as follows:

```py
Calculator1: TypeAlias = Callable[[int], int]
Calculator2: TypeAlias = Callable[[int], int]
```

I would like to ensure that the type checker is able to raise error in case they are used interchangeably. For example, I define additional functionality:

```py
def calc1(x: int) -> int:
    return x ** 2

def get_calc1() -> Calculator1:
    return calc1


def double_application(num: int, calc: Calculator2) -> int:
    return calc(calc(num))
```

Even when I pass in `Calculator1` in `double_application` it doesn't raise error. I tried this using the following functionality:

```py
def main():
    calc = get_calc1()
    val = 2
    final_val = double_application(val, calc)
    print(final_val)

main()
```

I am unclear on how I would be able to separate them without creating a `NewType`. Further, a `NewType` can't be defined over `Callable` of the follow sort. I had raised this question in a previous question ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76756668/newtype-for-callables-in-python)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use `NewType` for your desired semantics. To make `NewType` work with `Callable`s, you need an intermediate type that is both subclassable and a `Callable`. See [this mypy playground snippet](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.11&flags=strict&gist=062ee549c4d5653c08aed366a0bc6342) for how I use `SubclassableCallable` to achieve what you need. Declarations are also below:

```
@dataclass(frozen=True)
class SubclassableCallable:
    func: Callable[[int], int]

    def __call__(self, x: int, /) -> int:
        return self.func(x)

Calculator1 = NewType("Calculator1", SubclassableCallable)
Calculator2 = NewType("Calculator2", SubclassableCallable)
```

The resulting `mypy` error is, as you expect:

```
error: Argument 2 to "double_application" has incompatible type "Calculator1"; expected "Calculator2"  [arg-type]
```

Comment: The MyPy link doesn't lead to anything relevant. If I am to return a function of `Calculator1` type, am I supposed to do `Calculator1(SubclassableCallable(func))`?

Comment: @Zeeshanahmed My mistake, updated mypy link. Yes, you would need to do the nested instantiation.